# Runtime error 429 When trying to create ActiveX component

Tags: vb6, windows-8.1, activex, dcom

> Runtime Error 429 -ActiveX Component Can't Create Object

This error comes up when my program executes the following lines.

```
Private WithEvents CommClient As XXcommClient

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    'Initializes the CommClient object.
    Set CommClient = CreateObject("COMMLIBXLibCtl.XXcommClient") 'errors here
```

what is missing? >_<
i've already added XXCommLibX.dll as a reference in this project (and it contains the class definitions (i think that's what they're called) for XXcommClient and XXcommServer)

i'm running this on win8.1. i've already changed the access permissions and stuff in mmc comexp.msc /32 for "XXCom.XxInfo" (which contains the above code). the settings btw are none, everyone can edit, and interactive user.

**can someone please point me to the right direction?** i've been going in circles for the past few days huhuhuhuhu

Comment: If this is a DLL then DCOM settings don't matter and you are barking up the wrong tree.  The VB6 documentation lists a host of causes for this exception, my guess is that you (a.) don't have the DLL registered properly, (b.) are trying to use an incorrect ProgId string, or (c.) do not have a license to use this DLL.  Why are you using `CreateObject()` here anyway?

Comment: @Bob77 it might be b). Before using CreateObject, i used Set CommClient = new XXcommClient but still got the same error. How do i register dlls properly? >.<

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Bob77 had it right.
It was actually a) i did not have the dll registered properly.

XXCommLibX.dll was actually dependent on three other .dlls and two .exes. This detail was actually mentioned in the manual. It's embarrassing, really.

After properly registering the dll, i went back to using this line:

```
Set CommClient = new XXcommClient
```

... and it worked. >.<